# Using arithmetic and squeeze theorem, how to prove this sequence diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n\:=\:\frac{n!}{q^n}\:,\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:q>1$.
I want to show $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n\:=\:\infty $ WITHOUT using the definition of "tending to infinity of sequence", but to show that exist a sequence $b_n$, such that for large $N$, $\forall n\:>\:N\:\:\:\:b_n\le a_n$.
Then, show that $b_n\rightarrow \infty $, and that would tell me that $a_n\rightarrow \infty $.

The problem is i cant find that $b_n$. Can someone help me here? tnx!

Comment: $b_n=\frac{n!}{2q^n}= \frac{a_n}{2}$...? In other terms: do you have other assumptions on $b_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i found the easiest example:
First, we can see : $$\frac{n!}{q^n}\:=\:\frac{1}{q}\cdot \frac{2}{q}\cdot \frac{3}{q}\cdot ...\cdot \frac{q}{q}\cdot \frac{q+1}{q}\cdot ....\cdot \frac{n-1}{q}\cdot \frac{n}{q}$$.

becauese $q$ is constant, we can mark:  $K=\:\frac{1}{q}\cdot \frac{2}{q}\cdot \frac{3}{q}\cdot ...\cdot \frac{q}{q}$ 
and we will get:  $$a_n\:=\:K\cdot \frac{q+1}{q}\cdot ....\cdot \frac{n-1}{q}\cdot \frac{n}{q}$$

Now, because $q>1$:  $\frac{q+1}{q}\:>\:1,\:\:\:\frac{q+2}{q}\:>\:1\:......\frac{n}{q}\:>\:1$ , we can see that :
$a_n\:=\:K\cdot \frac{q+1}{q}\cdot ....\cdot \frac{n-1}{q}\cdot \frac{n}{q}$ > $K\cdot \frac{n}{q}$.
Let $b_n\:=\:K\cdot \frac{n}{q}$. (for these K and q), and clearly $b_n\rightarrow \infty $, so $a_n\rightarrow \:\infty \:$. end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the estimate of:

$$(N+n)! = N!\cdot (N+1)(N+2)\cdots(N+n) \geq N!\cdot N^n$$

so for large values of $N$, you have

$$a_{N+n} = \frac{(N+n)!}{q^{N+n}} \geq \frac{N!}{q^N}\cdot \frac{N^n}{q^n}$$

or, if $m = N+n$, that means

$$a_m \geq \frac{N!}{q^N}\frac{N^{m-N}}{q^{m-N}} = \frac{N!N^{-N}}{q^Nq^{-N}}\left(\frac{N}{q}\right)^m$$

for all values of $m$ larger than $N$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Observe that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}{q}$.

Fix an $N\ge 2q$. Then for $n\ge N$, we have $a^n\ge 2^{n-N}a_N$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $n_0 > 2q \to a_{n_0+1} \geq 2a_{n_0}\to a_{n_0+k} \geq 2^k\cdot a_{n_0}\to a_m\geq \frac{a_{n_0}}{2^{n_0}}\cdot 2^m, m \geq n_0+1$. Now choose $b_n = 2^n\cdot \frac{a_{n_0}}{2^{n_0}}$